# csv file is not loading into the directory what should i do

Tags: file

I'm having trouble importing a CSV file into RStudio. I've tried using the read.csv() function, but I keep encountering an error. Here are the details of my issue:

I'm running RStudio version 1.2.3 on Windows 10. The CSV file I'm trying to import is named "data.csv" and is located in my working directory.

ere's the code I'm using:
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'data.csv': No such file or directory
I've checked that the file exists in the correct directory, and I have read permissions for it. I also tried providing the full file path, but the error persists.

Could you please help me understand what could be causing this error and how I can successfully import the CSV file into RStudio?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!